# .bind() val on page load

Tags: jquery

Okay, let me break it down for you. We have a form that when submitted it reloads the page. However, in that form that we're submitting I want to grab a text input value and add THAT value to an element on page load. But this won't work...what am I doing wrong?

```
$('#btnDoneCampaignFields').bind('click',function(){
    var getValue = $('.field-set-wrap').find('.color-picker-frmfields').val();

    $('.sb-form > input').css('color', getValue);
});
```

Comment: "*But this won't work*": how? What happens?

Comment: If you're "reloading the page" (and not doing an async call), you either need to resort to server-side solutions to put it in the request response, or use a cookie and craft code to read your value(s) on page load and put them where you want them... When the page has loaded.

Comment: on page load, css color is not binding to the input

Comment: Is the code above running before or after the "page is reloaded/submitted"? If it's before... Well. The response to your form submit request obliterates that page if it's a non-async request. You're not giving the information we need, "binding" doesn't tell us much seeing your depiction of what's occurring.

Comment: how are you submitting the form? you may need to use Ajax for this to update you element before or after the submit.

Comment: It's running before. Sorry if I'm not explaining myself well enough here.

Comment: @RayEatmon yeah, The form is not ajax and I wanted to see if there was a none server-side route. I thought you could .bind() elements on page load...

Comment: `$.bind()` is just a bland way of saying attach in this case. You can look at Knockout.js for some compelling "data binding" features, but event these don't work across complete page reloads without server-client cooperation.

Comment: You may want to try .on() instead for delegation it has a similar effect but more helpful in your case. [jquery on function](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Read a bit on [stateless procotols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) (as HTTP is), and here is a [SO answer explaining what it means](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913763/what-does-it-mean-when-they-say-http-is-stateless). Cookies were an early way to bypass "statelessness" by adding textual data to each request that is, literally, constantly sent back and forth. Single page apps (Backbone.js, Knockout.js, Angular.js are some of the frameworks) use newer features like localStorage, sessionStorage, web sockets and asynchronous loading/pushState to make the client "fat".

Comment: If you're interested, [this talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEWTPFzt2-E) is also pretty informative on how HTTP is meant to work, and how it's abused (not looking at you, Twitter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are posting page, i.e. reloading, the page than you need to store that value somewhere to get it back when the request response is received by the browser.

If you are using html5 than you can do this:

```
$('#btnDoneCampaignFields').bind('click',function()
{
    var getValue = $('.field-set-wrap').find('.color-picker-frmfields').val();

    sessionStorage.Fieldvalue = getValue;
}
```

Using a `document.ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if (sessionStorage.Fieldvalue) {
        $('.sb-form > input').css('color', sessionStorage.Fieldvalue);
    }
});
```

Check about this in more detail: [What is HTML5 Web Storage?](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Good approach..but this needs a browser with HTML5 support

Comment: @ubercooluk - yes...if not want to user this approch than its good to use cookies...to achieve it.

Comment: Web Storage is nice. @ubercooluk - Support is pretty good at this point. I don't know that it's considered an HTML5 "aspect" (?) anymore.

Comment: Hmm...I like this and was the type of answering I was looking for. Our application is def HTML5 driven.

Comment: Should there be parentheses surrounding the IF statement?

Comment: Okay, I'm seeing the Fieldvalue in Chrome Developer Tools as a session key. However, it's not taking that Fieldvalue val and adding it to the .css() function. Using your code above.